# When does laravel envoyer replace the symbolic link of current?

Tags: laravel, laravel-envoyer

I am distributing the project through laravel envoyer.

I use AWS's EC2 Auto Scaling Group.

Instances that are maintained statically are distributed with Envoyer,

For other scaled-out instances, rolling updates are performed by replacing the AMI.

To replace the AMI every time the code is deployed, an aws cli command to replace the AMI is executed at the end of the deployment hook.

However, when checking the replaced AMI, the AMI was created in the state before the current symbolic link was changed.

In the deployment hook, isn't the Activate New Release step replacing the symlink in current?